# Implement Article KnowledgeBase vote stars picking and view stat updating

Tags: apex, visualforce, articles

Problem description:

I wanted to show the default preview knowledge article window when user click on an article from an articles list, in a modal window inside users portal site.

1. I use a bootstrap modal, because all the UI is already using
   bootstrap for the site.
2. Inside the modal I used iframe which directing to the article
   preview window (url path looks like this '/articles/' +
   article.Language + '/FAQ/' + article.UrlName). That works but the
   iframe window inside the modal had the portal site header, footer
   and other styling as well.
3. I wanted to show something more stylish, so to overcome the above
   issue I used my own style to populate the article fields inside the
   modal window, all went good, but I don't know how to reproduce the
   stars vote UI, and even if I know how I don't seems to find a way to
   update the vote stat (same goes for the view stat).

[image: vote stat example]

Solution help needed:

1. Reproduce vote stars UI selection.
2. Increase vote and view stat from code.

Some info I found that may help:

1. [Update view stat example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_update_viewstat.htm), but couldn't found something similar to this for vote stat.
2. [apex:vote tag](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_vote.htm), I tried this one with objectId equals to KnowledgeArticleId, but nothing was presented to screen (seems weird!).

Thank in advanced!

Comment: I have an idea which almost worked, I use jquery .load() --> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );, for the specific part of the voting in the standard page, but the stars are not shown probably because missing header script or css (.load not parsing back the header), I'm trying to import them manually just to check which parts are necessary...

Comment: I have found the css for the votes, but the functions for mouse event does not work, I will now try to find the salesforce js which provide them!